# Password not saving when creating user

Tags: django, django-forms, passwords, django-users

I know there are hundreds of posts about that topic but, in all of them, there is something slightly different from my own program and I can't adapt it to my program because the Django way of handling password is such a mess that I understand nothing. A little help would be greatly appreciated, I thank you in advance.

So, when a new user registers, everything works perfectly but, somehow, the password is not saved in the database. When I go to the admin interface, it tells me that the password format is invalid or the hashag function is not known.

Here is my code :

Forms.py

```
class InscriptionForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'password']
        widgets = {'username': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
                    'first_name': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
                    'last_name': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
                    'email': forms.EmailInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
                    'password': forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'})}

    def clean_password(self):
        password = self.cleaned_data['password']
        try:
            validate_password(password, user=self)
        except forms.ValidationError:
            self.add_error('password', password_validators_help_texts())

        return password
```

Views.py

```
def inscription(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = InscriptionForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            new_user = form.save()
            authenticate(username=form.cleaned_data['username'], password=form.cleaned_data['password'],)
            login(request, new_user)
            request.session['is_connected'] = True
            return redirect(inscription_suite)
    else:
        form = InscriptionForm()

    return render(request, 'inscription/inscription.html', {'form': form})
```

I already tried modifying the view like this :

```
def inscription(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = InscriptionForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            new_user = form.save(commit=False)
            new_user.password = make_password(form.cleaned_data['password'])
            authenticate(username=form.cleaned_data['username'], password=form.cleaned_data['password'],)
            login(request, new_user)
            new_user.save()
            request.session['is_connected'] = True
            return redirect(inscription_suite)
    else:
        form = InscriptionForm()

    return render(request, 'inscription/inscription.html', {'form': form})
```

But it raises the following error `ValueError at /inscription
Cannot force an update in save() with no primary key.`

Can someone help me please ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: You should use the `create_user` function for creating users https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/default/#creating-users

Comment: Yes I know this is the recommended way to do but I don't think the problem with password is related to the way I create users since I saw lots of topics of people that use ```create_user``` and still have the problem with password.

Comment: use set_password() to save the password otherwise it will save password as normal text. I think that's the error in your case.

Comment: Yes that solves the problem thank you, have a nice day !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must save password  using set_password().

```
def inscription(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = InscriptionForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            new_user = form.save(commit=False)
            password = form.cleaned_data['password'] # get password
            new_user.set_password(password) # set the password
            new_user.save() # save the user
            authenticate(username=form.cleaned_data['username'], password=form.cleaned_data['password'],)
            login(request, new_user)
            request.session['is_connected'] = True
            return redirect(inscription_suite)
    else:
        form = InscriptionForm()

    return render(request, 'inscription/inscription.html', {'form': form})
```

Comment: That solves the problem thank you and have a nice day !